# DNS zones priority

Tags: domain-name-system

We have configured internal dns zone **my-company**.
There is a record **example.live.my-company** which resolves to private address 192.168.0.1. resolv.conf is the following for the server:

```
search my-company
```

Now some organization registers name **example.live** and makes it publicly accessible, example.live resolves to some public address.
Question is, when server is trying to resolve address example.live what should be returned, public or private address? Does any description of such situation exist in RFC?

Comment: I think the search domain is added to whatever is entered only when lookups fail for whatever is entered.  So it would typically be check hosts file, check dns, append search domain and check dns again.  Not sure if it checks hosts file a second time after appending search domain.